# Baby Taylor BT1e didn't make sound at venue. The next day, it was fine

Tags: guitar, performing, pick-ups, live, semi-acoustic-guitar

I have asked a few resources and I can't get a good answer.

I was simply doing an open mic at a venue and when I plugged my guitar into their system, no noise came out. The performer just before me plugged in his acoustic-electric and did his gig. When I was up, all I did was transfer the 1/4 cable from his guitar to my guitar. The sound engineer at the venue tried to figure it out but he couldn't, so I eventually borrowed someone else's guitar. My guitar's pre-amp batteries were not dead and I made sure they were fresh. The day after the show, I plugged the guitar into a different PA system and it worked fine. At the venue, the guitar was plugged into their DI box, and then their mixer. This is the pick-up my guitar uses https://www.taylorguitars.com/guitars/acoustic/features/electronics/es-b

My Thoughts Are:

1. My batteries were good enough to turn on the tuner, but were dying
2. The fact that my guitar has a pre-amp messed something up. I don't think the previous performer had one.
3. The settings on the DI box were wrong for my guitar

Do any of you have any idea what happened, and how I can prevent this in the future? Thanks

Comment: We don't know your guitar. We don't know the guitar that worked. We don't know either PA systems, nor the DI box. In my experience, DIs are plug-and-play without many settings. The closest thing I would think of is that the cable wasn't sitting solidly in the jack. It's a big problem with right-angle jacks is that they don't fit in Tele jack cups, but for acoustics shouldn't have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience whenever a situation like you describe happens it’s always a simple operator error such as the battery was dead or your volume knob was not turned up. I would say that it was the volume knob on your guitar which was turned up by you the next day if you didn’t change batteries.

However, since we don’t know anything about the equipment or the competence of the people involved, there’s no way to know.